# Air Pressure Acting Below Object

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, classical-mechanics, pressure

Consider an object resting on a surface. If I had to find the net force on the object, I would write an equation as follows: weight = normal force.

But what about the air pressure that's acting on the surface of the object? Since object is resting on a surface, there is no air pressure acting from below the object to cancel out the air pressure acting on top of the object. So shouldn't the equation be: weight + air pressure force = normal force.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. However, it usually works out the same as if you ignored air pressure. Homework problems in beginning physics courses are often simplified so you can concentrate on the part of physics in the current chapter. So it is certainly true for your problem. So let's see why you can ignore it.

Consider an object not sitting on a surface. It has a top and bottom surface with area A. The force from air pressure on both surfaces is $pA$. The forces are in opposite directions, so the total is $0$. The object is not accelerated by air pressure.

Consider a surface with no object sitting on it. Often the back side of the surface is not shown in the problem. But it always exists. The surface is just the top surface of another object. And that object is always in air. This is true if the object is a table, or even if it is the entire Earth. So air pressure squeezes that object, but does not accelerate it.

This means you can think of an object sitting on a surface as an object sitting on another object. Air pressure acting on the pair together does not accelerate the pair.

Air pressure squeezes them together, but that is no different from how they are squeezed when sitting apart. The force on the table changes from $pA$ to $pA + w$. The $pA$ part cancels a similar $pA$ on the back of the table. The net force on the table is $w$.

Likewise, the force on the bottom of the object changes from $pA$ from air pressure to $pA + w$ from the normal force of the table. Again. $pA$ from the top and bottom cancel. leaving a net force of $w$ upward.

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding the question or this answer. For "an object resting on a surface", the net force is obviously zero, otherwise the object would not be resting.  The upward force of the table surface on the object must balance all downward forces on the object.  I don't understand how one can say that the net normal force upward from the table on the paper is just $w=mg$.  If a large thin sheet of smooth plastic rests on a smooth flat table, then the dominant force holding the sheet against the table is actually air pressure since $pA>>mg$. (Just try lifting it straight up.)

Comment: The upward force on the object is $w + pA$. Many objects do not perfectly match the shape of the table, so there is air between. In that case $w$ is from the table and $pA$ is from the air. If there is a good fit, then $w + pA$ is from the table. In the first case, we can ignore the equal and opposite $pA$ forces on the top and bottom of the object. That just leaves $w$ downward from gravity and an equal and opposite $w$ upward from the table. In the second case, it is hard to pick up the object until you pull them apart and let air in.

Comment: Yes, that is what I was expecting the answer to say, but it was not clear to me even after several readings.  I personally found your more succinct comment much clearer than the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your equation is correct only if the surface and the object are perfectly flat, so that they press flush against each other. However, this is almost never the case in real life,as there are minute gaps between the surfaces. Therefore, the difference is pressure between the top and bottom surface is negligible(for small objects) and we dont consider it.