# Consideration of air pressure when asking about the pressure of an object on the ground? Physics

Tags: pressure, fluid-statics

If the mass of the object and the area on which its force acts are given, one can calculate the pressure that it exerts with p = F/A. But do we have to add the air pressure to this quantity to get the total pressure on the ground?

Comment: This may help. [Air Pressure Acting Below Object](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/571789/37364)

Comment: [Gauge pressure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pressure_measurement#Absolute,_gauge_and_differential_pressures_—_zero_reference) is often (explicitly or implicitly) used or assumed to avoid worrying about atmospheric pressure.